# Fill space between Tkinter canvas objects with a colour

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

**Python 2.7.8, Windows 7**

I have subclassed the Tkinter canvas widget and I have added a new method to create a rectangle with rounded edges.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MyCanvas(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def create_rounded(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, r):
        self.create_arc(x1, y1, x1+r, y1+r, start=90, extent=90, style=tk.ARC)
        self.create_arc(x2-r, y1, x2, y1+r, start=0, extent=90, style=tk.ARC)
        self.create_arc(x1, y2-r, x1+r, y2, start=180, extent=90, style=tk.ARC)
        self.create_arc(x2-r, y2-r, x2, y2, start=270, extent=90, style=tk.ARC)
        self.create_line(x1+r/2, y1, x2-r/2, y1)
        self.create_line(x1, y1+r/2, x1, y2-r/2)
        self.create_line(x1+r/2, y2, x2-r/2, y2)
        self.create_line(x2, y1+r/2, x2, y2-r/2)
```

I want to fill the rounded rectangle I have created with a single color. How do I go about this.

[image: This is what I get when I run with some parameters]

[image: This is what I want]

Comment: @SDilmac It's not only the arcs I want to fill. I want to fill the space enclosed by the arc and the lines.

Comment: @SDilmac I am not creating any object with a namespace. I have added two images for clarification of what I want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of drawing the outline and trying to fill in the interior with red, why not build up the rounded rectangle out of pre-existing canvas objects?  Four circular pie slices for the corners, and two rectangles forming a cross? Something like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MyCanvas(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def create_rounded(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, r):
        self.create_arc(x1, y1, x1+r, y1+r, start=90, extent=90, style=tk.PIESLICE, fill = "red")
        self.create_arc(x2-r, y1, x2, y1+r, start=0, extent=90, style=tk.PIESLICE, fill = "red")
        self.create_arc(x1, y2-r, x1+r, y2, start=180, extent=90, style=tk.PIESLICE, fill = "red")
        self.create_arc(x2-r, y2-r, x2, y2, start=270, extent=90, style=tk.PIESLICE, fill = "red")
        self.create_rectangle(x1+r/2, y1-r/2, x2-r/2, y2+r/2, fill = "red")
        self.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="red")
```

I haven't tested this, so I may have gotten the coordinates wrong, or put in a syntax error, but I think you'll see what I mean.

Comment: The rectangles should be
        self.create_rectangle(x1+r/2, y1, x2-r/2, y2, fill=color)
        self.create_rectangle(x1, y1+r/2, x2, y2-r/2, fill=color)
But this leaves black lines

Answer (score 0):

I modified the suggestion from saulspatz to correct the coordinates as follows. Unfortunately it draws lines for the arcs and rectangles. I added width=0 but for some reason still see some lines. One option might be to draw over these lines with a line of the fill color. Seems a bit tedious.

```
class Rounded():
def __init__(self, canvas, x1, y1, x2, y2, r, color='red'):
    self.canvas = canvas  
    self.canvas.create_arc(x1, y1, x1+r, y1+r, start=90, extent=90, style=TK.PIESLICE, fill = color, width=0)
    self.canvas.create_arc(x2-r, y1, x2, y1+r, start=0, extent=90, style=TK.PIESLICE, fill = color, width=0)
    self.canvas.create_arc(x1, y2-r, x1+r, y2, start=180, extent=90, style=TK.PIESLICE, fill = color, width=0)
    self.canvas.create_arc(x2-r, y2-r, x2, y2, start=270, extent=90, style=TK.PIESLICE, fill = color, width=0)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1+r/2, y1, x2-r/2, y2, fill=color, width=0)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1+r/2, x2, y2-r/2, fill=color, width=0)
```

I then thought about drawing horizontal lines. The advantage here is that you could implement a gradient to the object. The code is here:-

```
    def using_lines(self):
    # Try to draw rounded rectangle using lines!
    xx = [3,5,6,7,8,8,9,9,9,10]
    zz = [10,9,9,9,8,8,7,6,5,3]
    x = 10
    y = 150
    width = 100
    height = 30
    radius = 10
    #self.canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x+width, y+height)
    r_width = width - 2*radius
    left = x + radius
    right = x + width - radius
    for r in range(radius):
        self.canvas.create_line(left, y+r, right, y+r, fill='green')
        left = x + radius - xx[r] 
        right = x + width - radius + xx[r]
    for r in range(height - 2 * r):
        self.canvas.create_line(x, y+radius+r, x + width, y+radius+r, fill='green')
    left = x
    right = x + width
    top = y + height - radius
    for r in range(radius):
        self.canvas.create_line(left, top+r, right, top+r, fill='green')
        left = x + (radius - zz[r])
        right = x + width - radius + zz[r]
```

I guessed the numbers to draw lines of different length to match an arc but I am sure a calculation could be devised.

The lines can all be given the same tag, so changing the entire color is easy. To add a border I also added the code from Charlito, though it didn't exactly match the lines I drew.

Forgive the crude code, I just wanted to quickly look at proof of concept before going further.

If speed is not important then the line lengths can be calculated. For standard buttons and labels, they can be pre-defined to match  a fixed radius. I am interested in making buttons and labels from these ideas.